# Forms not correlating with its query in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2007 and created a query based on a table of information. 
I created a form based on the query.
In the form, I made a textbox that I am going to use as the "search" field. I can type the name of a person in the textbox and I would like the form to only display those patients that have that particular text in their name.

In the query, I put under the Name field, under the criteria section: 
Like `"*" & [forms]![(name of form that has the textbox in it)]![(name of the textbox)] & "*"`

This works in the sense that any text that I put in the textbox, it shows only those people who have that text in their names in the query. However, the FORM isn't showing those same people! The Form isn't correlating with the query that it is supposed to be based on!

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Could you show exactly how your query looks like in your MS Access vba code?

Comment: If you're saying that query is used as the form's record source, then in the text box's After Update event, requery the record source: `Me.Requery`